# Unable to access data in collection for chart.js

Tags: html, angular, typescript, chart.js, mean

I am trying to access data from the collection to display in a chart using chart.js and MEAN stack.
I am retrieving the collection of data stored in the database but when i try displaying a specific data variable it does not show anything.
This is the collection of data being logged:

[image: all data in collection]

and this is the component typescript code associated:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartService.noOfEqu().subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      let areaCode = res['list'].map(res=>res.areaCode)
      let inoperEqu = res['list'].map(res=>res.inoperEqu)
      let operEqu = res['list'].map(res=>res.operEqu)
      let date = res['list'].map(res=>res.eventDate)
      
      let Dates = []
      date.forEach((res) => {
        let jsdate = new Date(res *1000)
        Dates.push(jsdate.toLocaleTimeString('en', {year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day:'numeric' }))
        
      });
console.log(Dates)
console.log(areaCode)
          })
      }
    }
```

However the Dates and Area Code does not display in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the "list" and replace areaCode with area

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartService.noOfEqu().subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      let areaCode = res.map(res=>res.area)
      let inoperEqu = res.map(res=>res.inoperEqu)
      let operEqu = res.map(res=>res.operEqu)
      let date = res.map(res=>res.eventDate)
      
      let Dates = []
      date.forEach((res) => {
        let jsdate = new Date(res *1000)
        Dates.push(jsdate.toLocaleTimeString('en', {year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day:'numeric' }))
        
      });
console.log(Dates)
console.log(areaCode)
          })
      }
    }
```